# Executar método de uma classe aninhada como propriedade em outra no C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflexão, propriedade

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
public class Feliz : IFeliz
{
   //public algumas propeiedades e tals... { get; set; }
   public bool EstaFeliz()
   {
      //Faz alguma coisa...
   }
}
```

E ela é uma propriedade em outra classe:

```
public Exemplo
{
   public IFeliz Feliz { get; set; }
   // Outras propriedades e métodos etc...
}
```

Agora dentro do meu executável estou criando por reflection uma instância do Exemplo. E quero acessar o método Feliz.EstaFeliz() através dele. Tem como?
Estou tentando algo assim:

```
Executor(string ClasseChamada) // onde ClasseChamada = "Exemplo"
{
   //Pega o objeto Exemplo blz! (já testado)
   Type ExemploType = Type.GetType(ClasseChamada + ",namespace") ;
   ConstructorInfo ExemploConstructor = ExemploType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
   object ExemploClassObject = ExemploConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { });

   //Tentativa de pegar a propriedade Feliz para chamar seu método...
   PropertyInfo FelizPropery = ExemploType.GetProperty("Feliz"); //PropertyInfo permitem chamar métodos?
   MethodInfo methodFeliz = FelizType.GetType().GetMethod("EstaFeliz");
   methodFeliz.Invoke(FelizPropery, null);
}
```

Como devem ter percebido estou meio perdido nessa segunda parte aí... alguém poderia me salvar?

Comment: A primeira pergunta que deve ser feita é porque está usando reflexão para algo que não precisa disto?

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção @Maniero. Eu simplifiquei muito o exemplo. Até para ser objetivo e facilitar as respostas. Preciso disso porque a classe Exemplo pode na verdade ser 1 de 60 outras classes que fazem parte da minha Persistencia. Recebo apenas o nome da classe como string dependendo de onde e por qual objeto ela será invocada no sistema.

Comment: Fiz até uma pequena mudança no contexto do meu exemplo para vc vizualizar melhor. Alterei o início do 3º trecho de código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlamBique, basicamente o problema é que você está tentando invocar um método de um objeto que ainda não existe.

Na sua definição de classe `Exemplo`, você tem uma propriedade do tipo `IFeliz` ainda não atribuída por nenhum objeto, então não há como você invocar um método.

Assumindo que você tenha uma `string` com o nome da classe a ser atribuída à propriedade `Feliz` (se for a mesma `string`, mais fácil), basta apenas você criar uma nova instância dessa classe e atribuí-la à propriedade. Normalmente faço assim:

```
Type tipo = Type.GetType("namespace." + nomeClasse);
var instancia = Activator.CreateInstance(tipo);
```

> Até aí só criei o objeto a ser atribuído à propriedade de ExemploClassObject

```
FelizPropery.SetValue(ExemploClassObject, instancia);
```

> Essa foi a atribuição. Agora você tem a propriedade `Feliz`, do objeto de tipo `Exemplo` apontando para um objeto do tipo `Feliz`.
>
> Segui seu nome de variável `FelizPropery`...

Tirando o fato de que você não precisa fazer a atribuição para invocar o método, agora você tem a `instancia` na mão para invocá-lo, sabendo que é o mesmo objeto que foi atribuído à propriedade `Feliz` do objeto do tipo `Exemplo`.

```
MethodInfo metodo = tipo.GetMethod("EstaFeliz");
bool resultado = (bool)metodo.Invoke(instancia, null);
```

Comment: Obrigado! Estou no onibus agora. Mas ch3gando em casa testo e posto o resultado.

Comment: Arao você é um gênio! Obrigado! Isso faz todo o sentido. Eu estava encarando que a instancia estava "automaticamente" no objeto do qual pertencia (ou seja em Exemplo). Mas como você bem mostrou, preciso criar ela. Testei aqui e funcionou sem problema. Isso resolve um problemão meu. Vou fazer um post em breve com o código completo do que realmente estou fazendo e coloco o link aqui pra vc ver o que me ajudou a construir. Abraços!

Comment: Boa AlamBique! Espero que esteja fazendo algo interessante!